# What's an easy way to do find file then fuzzy search by filename?

Tags: find-file

I am trying to learn emacs in order to use orgmode.

I came from vscode universe.

There's a Cmd+P in vscode that allows search by filename easily. Looks like this.

[image]

Then i can use cursor keys to go up and down and hit enter it will open as new tab.

Is there an equivalent of this in emacs and open in either new buffer or new window?

I have installed dired, but i think it forces me to type out the exact path

Comment: The question isn't too clear. Your screenshot doesn't show the input pattern that's being matched, and you didn't cite it. What kind of fuzzy matching are you asking about? And Emacs `find-file` (`C-x C-f`) and Dired both support various kinds of fuzzy matching, depending on your value of option `completion-styles`. (Neither forces you to type the whole absolute file name ("exact path").

Comment: And it looks like your screenshot and part of your description are about navigating through a list of *recent* files. Going up and down with cursor keys to pick a file name is not using any kind of fuzzy matching...

Comment: IMO, the first comment + built-in `ido-mode` + built-in `project-find-file` may serve as good starting points.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives, but I use projectile. It lets me open a file within a project by typing only a short portion of the name, and not necessarily just a prefix. You can adjust somewhat how fuzzy the search is with other libraries, such as ido-mode.

It has a few other related features, such as searching the whole project for text, compiling the project, and so on.

https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile